# ¿Como calcular los dias entres fechas?

Tags: php, date, pdo

#Estimado estoy con esta consulta que me muestra varios atributos de una revision técnica. La idea es tomar $todayDate que me muestra la fecha de hoy. con la fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica por ejemplo (la fecha hoy 13/04/2022 y fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica (20/03/2022)) si hacemos el calculo faltan 7 dias hay una funcion que se llama diff que hace el calculo pero mi error es hacer ese calculo y enviarlo junto con la sentencia o alguna forma de enviarlo

```
 <?php

$todayDate=new DateTime('now');

 require("Conexion/basedd.php");
    $sentencia =("SELECT id_revision_tecnica,patente_tracto,numero_factura_revision_tecnica,date_format(fecha_revision_tecnica,'%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_revision_tecnica,date_format(fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica, '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica ,detalle_revision_tecnica,total_revision_tecnica, factura_revision_tecnica FROM revision_tecnica INNER JOIN tracto on tracto.id_tracto=revision_tecnica.tracto_id_tracto");
   
   $data = $base->query($sentencia)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode( array('data'=>$data) );
?>
```

Comment: Viendo que incluyes la etiqueta de JavaScript, mucha gente considera que el cálculo de información redundante en servidor es desaconsejable salvo que ahorre mucha información de transferencia. Si puedes enviar las dos fechas, ¿te valdría una respuesta en la que se calcule la diferencia de días en JavaScript (en cliente)?

Comment: @AlexanderVega el dato proviene de la bbdd y $todayDate=new DateTime('now'); te lo entrega el sistema por la fecha

Comment: Si entendí bien lo tratado en su otra pregunta, quiere, por cada fila en la base de datos, la diferencia en días entre una fecha dada (que se encuentra en la base de datos) y la fecha de hoy. ¿Es así? Si es así, de qué tipo es la columna `fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica` en la base de datos? Por cierto, debería evitar esos nombres kilométricos en sus elementos.

Comment: @A.Cedano fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica tipo date

Comment: Y ¿en qué SGBD está su base de datos: MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle ...?

Comment: @A.Cedano MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener la diferencia en días entre la fecha actual y cada fecha de la tabla, se puede usar [`DATEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) de este modo:

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica,CURDATE()) AS diffDays,
    id_revision_tecnica,
    patente_tracto,
    numero_factura_revision_tecnica,
    date_format(fecha_revision_tecnica,'%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_revision_tecnica,
    date_format(fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica, '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica ,
    detalle_revision_tecnica,total_revision_tecnica,
    factura_revision_tecnica 
FROM revision_tecnica 
INNER JOIN tracto ON     
    tracto.id_tracto=revision_tecnica.tracto_id_tracto;
```

Esta consulta arrojará una columna llamada `diffDays` con esa diferencia de días ya calculada por cada fila obtenida, luego, usas esa columna para mostrar el dato.

#### Recomendación

Evita el uso de nombres kilométricos en nombres de tablas o columnas. Esto produce un código demasiado verboso que a la larga es complicado de analizar o depurar. Algo que ayuda a abreviar es usar una convención de nombre en inglés. Y, no es una buena idea poner nombres de tablas en las columnas de las mismas.

Por ejemplo, si la tabla se llama `revision_tecnica`, no tiene sentido nombre a esta columna: `fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica`, bastaría con `fecha_vencimiento` o, si optas por convención de nombre en inglés: `date_of_expire`.

Otras convenciones son aún mejores, por ejemplo, *camelCase* te evita los guiones bajos, y, para mi gusto, es más elegante: `dateOfExpire`.

Comment: Gracias estimado por el comentario

Answer (score 3):

### Con mysql

Modifica tu sentencia con

```sql
SELECT ...todo los campos que tenías,
      DATEDIFF(NOW(), fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica) as diferencia_dias
FROM ...
INNER JOIN ...
```

Eso debería añadir un campo diferencia_dias con la diferencia de días en todos los registros que devuelve la base de datos.

### Desde PHP (no recomendado)

Para date/datetimes, date_diff (alias de diff, también válido) es la solución. Es muy común ver la conversión directamente de la diferencia a un array de php, así que te lo dejo de esa manera si te resulta más cómodo.

```php
$diff = (array) date_diff($date1, $date2);
$dias = diff['days']
```

Tendrías que meter esos días en cada registro de `$data`. Me parece que podrías hacer algo como:

```php
$data = $base->query($sentencia)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($data as $registro) {
    $diff = (array)  date_diff($registro['fecha_vencimiento_revision_tecnica'], $todayDate);
    $registro['diferencia_dias'] = diff['days']
}
```

Eso provocará que cuando se codifique en json, cada registro incluya un campo `diferencia_dias`

#### ACTUALIZO: Por qué no recomiendo ninguna de estas opciones en muchos casos

Aprovecho a extender un poco esto, después del pequeño debate con A.Cedano en los comentarios.

En caso de que esta información vaya a un cliente con capacidad de tratamiento de los datos (por ejemplo un navegador con javascript), la diferencia de días es **información redundante**, y ni siquiera la primera opción es aconsejable, ya que la puede calcular directamente el cliente. Esto tiene 3 ventajas importantes:

1. Menor transferencia de datos (es solo un int redundante por registro, vale, pero si son miles de registros son miles de int).
2. Se descarga el tratamiento en sistemas críticos. El SGBD no hace magia, esa diferencia la tiene que calcular para cada registro. Aunque estén optimizados para este tipo de operaciones, sigue siendo más operaciones en un sistema donde el rendimiento es crítico.
3. Se disminuye el acoplamiento a la implementación del SGBD. Supón que de pronto es necesario cambiar a otro SGDB en SQL (PostgreSQL por ejemplo). Es probable que la función datediff funcione diferente o no funcione en absoluto. La dependencia de implementaciones es algo que siempre se busca evitar, y más a nivel de sistemas.

Dado que por los comentarios se especifica que este no es el caso, es preferible depender del SGBD, ya que de todas formas ya el sistema está acoplado a él (se está usando sintaxis SQL conociendo la implementación del SGBD, en lugar de una abstracción o un sistema ORM). Por lo que el tratamiento en SELECT, que coincide con la respuesta de A.Cedano, es completamente válido y preferible al tratamiento desde php (que no está tan optimizado como un SGBD para ello).

Comment: @keane1991 entiendo que quieres decir que no envías finalmente esta respuesta a un cliente con JavaScript (también veo que se ha eliminado la etiqueta), ignora entonces la última parte. He actualizado la respuesta con otra opción en mysql, viendo que es el SGBD que usas. Coméntame si te es válida.

Comment: ¿Por qué pones que con MySQL no es recomendado? Creo que para este caso es mejor calcularlo desde MySQL, pues así no precisa un posterior tratamiento de los datos, pudiendo pasar a consumirlos directamente.

Comment: Porque yo soy de la escuela de no dejar las responsabilidades adicionales al tratamiento de datos al SGBD, ni siquiera al servidor, para no acoplar todo el sistema a lógica externa que luego debe volver realizarse de cambiar implementación o saturar sistemas críticos. Es una mirada más desde el punto de vista de ingeniería de software. Quizás tengas razón y el "no recomendado" esté demás si no añado esta explicación. Es decir, soy de los que no apoyan dejar lógica de tratamiento redundante en sistemas críticos.

Comment: @AlexanderVega el principal responsable del tratamiento de los datos es el SGBD, es él quien guarda los datos, esa es su razón de ser y es relativamente simple calcular una diferencia en días partiendo de un dato que ya existe en la tabla. Si esto se hace en PHP, o en el cliente, tendrás que desempaquetar los datos para hacer este tratamiento, siendo todo más costoso y exponiendo los datos a error de que algo falle en ese tratamiento posterior. No tiene sentido, pudiendo traer ya ese valor calculado en la consulta SQL.

Comment: @A.Cedano la clave aquí está en que ya se entrega el dato de la fecha de vencimiento, en cliente se desempaquetan los datos porque deben ser consumidos (qué gracia si no). La lógica en cliente es preferible antes que en un sistema crítico. Por otra parte, el SGBD es el principal responsable del almacenamiento de los datos, no de su tratamiento, eso ya es una opinión y visión completamente personal o incluso una decisión de diseño del sistema de información. Añadir que entre más responsabilidad de tratamiento se le da al SGBD, más se depende de él, algo malo desde la visión de un ing. software

Comment: Creo que el propósito aquí es consumir la respuesta `$data` en el cliente, en un datatable. Si traes la diferencia en días ya calculada, se podrá consumir `$data` sin ningún tratamiento posterior. En caso contrario, tendrás que desempaquetar `$data` de nuevo (en el servidor o en el cliente), y calcular la diferencia por cada día, cuidando además de que la fecha (en el caso del cliente) sea la adecuada. Entiendo lo que dices en tu comentario, pero creo que para este caso lo mejor es traer la diferencia en días ya calculada desde la BD. Con eso no creo que se le esté tirando nada extraño a ella.

Comment: @A.Cedano Comprendo. Mi recomendación sigue siendo la misma, aunque al SGBD le cueste apenas nada y el cliente tenga que desempaquetar varias veces la información recibida, si el cliente no tiene otras cargas ni responsabilidades críticas, será preferible. Otra cosa distinta es que el cliente sea a su vez otro sistema crítico, como el servidor renderizando con php. Lo que pasa es que esta pregunta al principio tenía etiqueta JavaScript, y junto el json_encode, pensé que el cliente era algún consumidor web (navegador por ejemplo), lo que reducía además los datos transferidos. Un saludo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo en casi todo, no hay por qué recargar innecesariamente al servidor o a la base de datos. Pero, a mi, juicio, para este caso concreto, no hay por qué volver a recorrer los datos, para calculcar la diferencia en días de cada fila obtenida. Por mi parte, considero que hacer esto no recarga a la BD significativamente, y que es mucho más arriesgado exponer los datos a errores en un cálculo posterior. En cualquier caso hay que evaluar lo que sea mejor, según el contexto, tanto en el servidor, como en el cliente y en la aplicación en sí misma. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano coincido, en la evaluación y monitorización está la clave. A veces pecamos de buscar excesivamente el rendimiento. Quizás me he llevado demasiados palos tras decidir erróneamente que "esto no es tanta carga para la BD" cuando el sistema ha crecido, y quizás ahora tengo miedo de toda consulta avanzada. Un saludo.

Comment: @A.Cedano estimado me puedes ayudar con la orientación https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537525/se-puede-enviar-mensaje-por-sms-correo-o-whatsapp-a-través-de-cron?noredirect=1#comment952472_537525